Why isn't my Angular code showing the correct output?
My task was to take an email address into input and check each character, if the character is in Hebrew - convert it to English
The problem with the code is that it fails to convert correctly, I wrote the following text in the input field: "r0556" and it was supposed to display "r0556" instead it displays all kinds of double and long characters as you can see in the picture
This is the code snippet of the html page
<h1>נא הכנס כתובת מייל</h1>
<input (keyup)="getLetter($event)" (mouseover)="onComment()" (mouseleave)="offComment()" 
type="text">
<div id="comment">{{comment}}</div>
<button type="button" (click)="clickButton()">{{button}}</button>

And this is the code snippet of the TypeScript page
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-email-adress',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule],
  templateUrl: './email-adress.component.html',
  styleUrl: './email-adress.component.css'
})
export class emailAddressComponent {
  comment = "";
  onComment() {
    this.comment = "חובה למלא כתובת מייל"
  }
  offComment() {
    this.comment = "";
  }

  HebrewLetters = ['א', 'ב', 'ג', 'ד', 'ה', 'ו', 'ז', 'ח', 'ט', 'י', 'כ', 'ל', 'מ', 'נ', 'ס', 'ע', 'פ', 'צ', 'ק', 'ר', 'ש', 'ת'];
  EnglishLetters = ['t', 'c', 'd', 's', 'v', 'u', 'z', 'j', 'y', 'h', 'f', 'k', 'n', 'b', 'x', 'g', 'p', 'm', 'e', 'r', 'a', ','];
  emailAddress = "";

  getLetter(eventLetter: any) {
    let inputLetter = eventLetter.target.value;
    let index = this.HebrewLetters.indexOf(inputLetter);

    if (index !== -1) {
      this.emailAddress += this.EnglishLetters[index];
    } else {
      this.emailAddress += inputLetter;
    }

    if (eventLetter.keyCode === 13) {
      eventLetter.target.value = this.emailAddress;
      alert("This email address: " + this.emailAddress);
      this.emailAddress = "";
    }
  }

  button = "@gmail.com";
  clickButton() {
    this.emailAddress += this.button;
    alert("כתובת המייל שנקלטה היא: " + this.emailAddress)
  }

}




The problem is your logic: it's set to check a single key, but you check entire input value, concatenating it with local variable, which then causes the described duplicating behaviour, and the two variables differ...
So, you could listen for key code (eventLetter.key), however, it would not be effective with cut copy pasting etc.
To allow cut/copy/paste/backspace/delete etc., why not check and replace all characters from the input value, and also, combine it with local emailAddress, because now they're split, and will differ, and it would make sense to show the user that the characters are being replaced (but if you want to separate them, you could, but you need to make sure that they're connected, especially in case of backspace/delete/copy/paste etc.).
Try this code (explanations in comments), you can refactor it based on your use case:
  getLetter(eventLetter: KeyboardEvent) {

    // get input value
    let value = (eventLetter.target as HTMLInputElement).value;

    // get unique cahrs
    const chars = [...new Set(value.split(''))];

    // check and replace all chars, mutate input
    chars.forEach(char=>{
      
      let index = this.HebrewLetters.indexOf(char);

      if (index !== -1) {
        value = value.replaceAll(char, this.EnglishLetters[index])
      }
    });

    // connect with email address
    this.emailAddress = value;
    

    if (+eventLetter.code === 13) {
      alert("This email address: " + this.emailAddress);
      this.emailAddress = value = "";
    }    

    console.log('emailAddress', this.emailAddress);

    
  }

